# How to preserve CoundDownTimer on device rotation?

Tags: android, android-layout, time

I have 2 layouts portrait and landscape. Integers preservation works fine, but I can not reproduce it similarly with `long` and `CoundDownTimer`.

Before in onCreate I add

```
long timer = 2000;
int bottles = 10;
CountDownTimer delayTop;
```

Within onCreate

```
    delayTop = new CountDownTimer(timer, 10) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long ms) {
            timer = ms;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            cancel();
        }
    };
    delayTop.start();
```

As it can be seen both `int` and `long` are set before creation and `long` is updated during timer run. I used `log.i` to check and everything works at this step fine.

onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)

```
    outState.putInt("count", bottles );
    outState.putLong("delayms", timer);
```

onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)

```
    bottles = savedInstanceState.getInt("count");
    Log.i("msss", "delay ms " +savedInstanceState.getLong("delayms"));
    delayTop = new CountDownTimer(savedInstanceState.getLong("delayms"), 10) { ...
```

Restoration phase is not working as intended. Somehow `int` value is fine while `long` always get reset to 2000 after rotation considering that it was declared before outside creation method.

Question is how to preserve that timer to use it in new timer with remaining time?

Comment: Are you overriding `protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` or  `public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)` ? 
Edit : I just saw it is `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`

Comment: Can you provide more code? It looks like a problem of scope. Also, can you put a log in the onSaveInstanceState to ensure that you are putting into the extras exactly what you think you are?

Comment: @jonathanrz nice find! I never thought to put log there. Unfortunately after testing `onSave` value is also somehow reseted / different (same as in Restore) from last value of timer. I set another log on button click to make sure that timer has reached its minimum and only after it I do device rotation. Also strange find timer never reaches 0, it stops on range 11-19 with constant value.

Comment: @jonathanrz another discovery _log.i_  within `onClick` and `onSave/onRotate` show different values even tho timer value is one for all and declared before `onCreate`. And both reset to yet unknown value after roration. Seems like it is not 2000 but less